# proot required as dependence?

Tags: linux, centos, ansible

i was tring to install ansible via yum repo and i keep getting this error msg which i never came cross before ,

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package ansible-tower.noarch 0:2.1.1-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: proot for package: ansible-tower-2.1.1-1.el6.noarch
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: ansible-tower-2.1.1-1.el6.noarch (ans)
           Requires: proot
```

What is proot ? its not package as far as i know

any advise for this ?

Comment: are you trying to install Ansible or Tower? Based on your output, it's the latter.

Answer (score 1):

> **PRoot** is a user-space implementation of chroot, mount --bind, and binfmt_misc.

If it is not available in the CentOS repositories it can be found here: http://proot.me/

(but you probably already know this ;) )